# Comparable Protocol

Tags: swift, comparable, swift-protocols

I am going through Apple' "App Development with Swift" documentation and trying the examples in Protocols part. In the Comparable Protocol part I tried the following code without adding `Comparable` to structure references and didn't face any problems, it is working :

```
struct Employee: Equatable {
    var firstName : String
    var lastName : String
    var jobTitle : String
    var phoneNumber : String

    static func ==(lhs: Employee, rhs : Employee) -> Bool {
        return lhs.firstName == rhs.firstName && lhs
        .lastName == rhs.lastName
    }
    static func <(lhs: Employee, rhs : Employee) -> Bool {
        return lhs.lastName < rhs.lastName
    }

}

let employee1 = Employee(firstName: "Ben", lastName: "Atkins", jobTitle: "Front Desk", phoneNumber: "415-555-7767")
let employee2 = Employee(firstName: "Vera", lastName: "Carr", jobTitle: "CEO", phoneNumber: "415-555-7768")
let employee3 = Employee(firstName: "Grant", lastName: "Phelps", jobTitle: "Senior Manager", phoneNumber: "415-555-7770")
let employee4 = Employee(firstName: "Sang", lastName: "Han", jobTitle: "Accountant", phoneNumber: "415-555-7771")
let employee5 = Employee(firstName: "Daren", lastName: "Estrada", jobTitle: "Sales Lead", phoneNumber: "415-555-7772")

let employees = [employee1, employee2, employee3, employee4, employee5]
let employeesSorted = employees.sorted(by: <)

for employee in employeesSorted {
    print(employee)
}
```

But when I tried to sort with greater than operator (<):

```
print("Decending")

let employeesSorted2 = employees.sorted(by: >)

for employee in employeesSorted2 {
    print(employee)
}
```

An error message occured:

> error: referencing operator function '>' on 'Comparable' requires that 'Employee' conform to 'Comparable'
>   let employeesSorted2 = employees.sorted(by: >)

Do you have a valid explanation for this inconsistency?

Comment: just stating that it is "not working" is too vague.  `struct Employee {
    let firstName, lastName, jobTitle, phoneNumber: String
}` implement your equatable operator `extension Employee: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: Employee, rhs: Employee) -> Bool {
        return (lhs.firstName, lhs.lastName) == (rhs.firstName, rhs.lastName)
    }
}` and the comparison operator `extension Employee: Comparable {
    static func < (lhs: Employee, rhs: Employee) -> Bool {
        return (lhs.firstName, lhs.lastName) < (rhs.firstName, rhs.lastName)
    }
}`

Comment: Thank You Leo,  I got some answers below. it is clearer now. How does swift knows that I am implementing the "==" or "<"? Can I implement "<<<<" function like "employee1 <<<< employee2" , let's say to compare the second characters of the last name? I tried and not working ( vague again :) ) . Does swift imports some libraries which includes "==" or "<" operators?

Answer (score 2):

`Comparable` requires that you implement the `<` operator, it then uses that function, along with the implementation of `==` to figure out the implementation of `>`, `<=` and `>=`.

This will only happen if you declare that your struct is `Comparable`, if you don't, the compiler doesn't know what function to use.

Just declare your struct as comparable: 
`struct Employee: Equatable, Comparable`

Comment: Of coarse it needs Comparable, I am not questioning that. First code stack works without adding Comparable, which has sorting part less "than", ".sort(<)". I am questioning how can less than work with only Equatable Protocol.

Comment: @YahyaOz that's because you have implemented the `<` operator yourself. If you implemented `>` too, descending sort would also work. `Comparable` on the other hand gives you the `>` implementation automatically using `<` and `==` as it has already explained perfectly in this answer

Comment: Why is `>` not just the opposite of `<`?

Comment: @LinusGeffarth because `not <` is `>=`, it is not `>`.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth Because `a < b` does not imply `!(a > b)`, because it could be the case that `a == b`, in which one is neither greater nor less than the other

Comment: Indeed, I didn't think of that. Thanks rmaddy & Alexander.

Comment: Thank you David, it is clearer now. How does swift knows that I am implementing  the "==" or "<"? Can I implement "<<<<" function like employee1 <<<< employee2 , let's say to compare the second characters of the last name? I tried and not working. Does swift imports some libraries which includes "==" or "<" operators?

Comment: @YahyaOz `==` is a requirement of `Equatable`. `<` is a requirement of `Comparable`. Swift automatically provides a default implementation of `!=` for Equatable types (implemented as just `!(a == b)`, and default implementations of `<=`, `>`, `>=` for `Comparable` types (implanted as `(a < b) && (a==b)`, `!(a <= b)` and `!(a < b)`, respectively). These operators are requirements of the protocols, but just like any other functions, subscript, or property, you're free to define them even if you don't declare conformance to the protocol.

Answer (score 0):

The `Comparable` protocol requires the `<` operator. You cannot conform to `Comparable` without a `<` operator. `Colllection.sorted()` requires `Comparable` conformance.

Conforming to `Comparable` automatically gives you definitions of the `>`, `>=`, and `<=` operators (using the `<` you supply). If you conform to `Comparable`, you can use the `>` operator provided by the `Comparable` conformance as a comparison function.

The `<`  operator does not require the `Comparable` protocol. You can implement (and explicitly use) the `<` operator without conforming to `Comparable`. `Collection.sorted(by:)` does not require `Comparable` conformance, and you can treat the `<` operator as a comparison function.

Comment: Thank you Rob, it is clearer now. How does swift knows that I am implementing the "==" or "<"? Can I implement "<<<<" function like "employee1  <<<<  employee2" , let's say to compare the second characters of the last name? I tried and not working. Does swift imports some libraries which includes "==" or "<" operators?

Comment: The `==` and `<` operators are defined by the standard library. Read about defining custom operators in [*The Swift Programming Language*](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AdvancedOperators.html#ID46).